añadir un proyecto de windows form de c# para usar componentes personalizados
buenas a la comunidad y gracias de antemano.
la cuestion es que estoy desarrollando una aplicacion windows forms en c#, y tengo un proyecto que es otra aplicacion de windows form pero que solo contiene componentes graficos personalizados, me gustaria saber como utilizar el proyecto que tiene los componentes graficos personalizados para usar dichos componentes en la aplicacion que estoy desarrollando. no se si la forma correcta de decirlo sea que quisiera saber si hay forma de usar el proyecto de interfaz grafica como una libreria en mi proyecto.
saludos

No.. por lo menos lo que decis no se puede.. si podrias usar los componentes, siempre y cuando esten en un proyecto propio separado...

@gbianchi logre compilar el proyecto donde estan los controles personalizados como una libreria, agregue los controles de manera manual al toolbox y puedo usar incluso los formularios puedo hacer que hereden de los forms personalizados que estan en el proyecto compilado como libreria, ahora el problema que presento es que cuando hago que un form herede de alguno de los personalizados no puedo editar las propiedades de los componentes

ok.. mejor.. y no, no vas a poder, a menos que pongas que son editables... en el componente personalizado.. y tenes que programarlo...
